# Upgrading JupyterHub helm release w/ new docker image, but old image is being used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm

I have a JupyterHub notebook server, and I am running on managed kubernetes on aws (EKS). My docker repository is AWS ECR.

I am iteratively developing my docker image for testing.

My workflow is:

1. Update the docker image
2. Update docker image tag in helm release config `config.yaml`
3. Upgrade helm release `helm upgrade jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --version=0.7.0 --values config.yaml`
4. Test the changes to docker image

However, the old docker image is still being used?

**How must I change my development workflow, so that I can simply update docker image, and test?**

Additional info:

- Helm chart (public): https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/

Edit:

**Additional troubleshooting steps taken:**

Tried deleting the helm release and re-installing:

```
helm delete --purge jhub && helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --namespace jhub --version=0.7.0 --values config.yaml
```

Tried deleting the helm release AND namespace, and re-installing:

```
helm delete --purge jhub && kubectl delete namespace jhub && helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --namespace jhub --version=0.7.0 --values config.yaml
```

Also tried overriding `imagePullPolicy` value to `Always` (per Mostafa's suggestion in his answer)

```
hub:
  imagePullPolicy: Always
```

None of these work. Old, original docker image is still being used.

What is strange, is that when I inspect the docker images currently being used in my kubernetes cluster, I see the new docker image. But it is not the one being used.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"

# output:
...
<AWS_ACCOUNT>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<REPO>:NEW_TAG  # <-- not actually being used in jupyerhub
...
```

Edit(2):
I checked pod description, and found strange event messsage:
I checked one of my pod descriptions and saw a strange event message

```
  Normal  Pulled                  32m   kubelet,  <<REDACTED>>  Container image "<AWS_ACCOUNT>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<REPO>:NEW_TAG" already present on machine
```

The image being referred to above is my new image, that I just uploaded to image repo. It is impossible for the image to already be downloaded on the cluster. Somehow, the hash is the same for both the original image and the new image, or this is a bug?

Comment: For each docker image change you need to create a new docker container to use the new image and see the changes reflected

Comment: What is the `imagePullPolicy` value in your helm chart ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein -- The chart is not mine, it is public: `https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/`. I checked the chart and the value is `IfNotPresent ` -- so, this explains why docker image is not updating. Now, I guess the question is: can I over-ride this value? Or do I have to fork and modify the chart directly?

Comment: @MostafaHussein If you know how I can accomplish this, please feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: @JamesWierzba I will post it

Answer (score 2):

The docker image might not updated due to having `imagePullPolicy` set to `IfNotPresent` which means the following according to [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/):

> The default pull policy is IfNotPresent which causes the Kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists. If you would like to always force a pull, you can do one of the following:
>
> - set the imagePullPolicy of the container to Always.
> - omit the imagePullPolicy and use :latest as the tag for the image to use.
> - omit the imagePullPolicy and the tag for the image to use.
> - enable the [AlwaysPullImages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#alwayspullimages) admission controller

In your case you can set the value of `imagePullPolicy` to `Awlays` inside `config.yaml` while you deploying the new chart in order to make it pull the newest docker image of your code

```
# Add this in your config.yaml (check if hub: is already exist to avoid overriding it)
hub:
  imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: But, if the chart is installed from public repo, is there any way for me to override `imagePullPolicy` from my release config? e.g. `helm upgrade jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --version=0.7.0 --values config.yaml` where `config.yaml` will have my overridden `imagePullPolicy`

Comment: let me check the original values.yaml and get back to you

Comment: I apologize, I originally phrased my question incorrectly. I mixed up the terminology of `chart` and `release`

Comment: @JamesWierzba please check my answer

Comment: Hi Mostafa, I've tried your suggestion and it did not work unfortunately. I've updated my question with all of the things I've tried. At this point, the only thing I can think to try is to completely tear down my kubernetes cluster. I obviously don't want to do this. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @JamesWierzba I would suggest using `kubectl` to update the image: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment but honestly still thinking about why the pull didn't work

Comment: @JamesWierzba have you checked the pod logs as it might tell us something

Comment: Also can you add the result of your pod description ? don't forget to remove any sensitive data before adding it to your question

Comment: Here is the output for describe pods https://gist.github.com/wierzba3/dac8513a3e9bde2453de8944352b41eb (sensitive info scrubbed) -- I noticed an event stating that my new image is already present on the machine, which can't be true, because the image is new and had just been uploaded to docker repo. Looks like that might be a clue to the issue? Maybe the new docker image somehow is generating the same hash?